# Dynamic conditional correlation in Stata

Tags: correlation, stata, garch

I am testing the co-movement between 2 exchanges by using the dynamic conditional correlation (DCC) developed by Robert Engle (2002). I want to apply this method in stata 12 and used this command:

```
Mgarch DCC (var1 var2=), arch(1) garch(1) distribution(t)
```

I read that it should give me a column with correlations per time unit. But i am not getting this colums. Does someone have any idea how to apply the DCC in Stata 12?

Comment: If your only interest here is how to get Stata to do this, this question is off-topic for CV (it may be on-topic for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), I'm not sure). You may want to read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq). Are you wondering / do you have a question about garch more generally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the help file for `-mgarch dcc postestimation-`. You will find the following example of computing the dynamic correlations and their forecasts.

```
webuse stocks
mgarch dcc (toyota nissan = , noconstant) (honda = , noconstant), ///
    arch(1) garch(1)
tsappend, add(50)
predict H*, variance dynamic(2016)
tsline H_nissan_toyota H_honda_toyota H_honda_nissan if t>1600, ///
    legend(rows(3)) xline(2015)
```

which produces the graph of the dynamic correlations between the three individual stocks.

[image]

---

### Update 1

If you are only interested in the in-sample fits of the conditional correlations, then it becomes really simple, and you can drop the `tsappend` command:

```
webuse stocks
mgarch dcc (toyota nissan = , noconstant) (honda = , noconstant), ///
    arch(1) garch(1)
predict H*, variance
tsline H_nissan_toyota H_honda_toyota H_honda_nissan if t>1600, ///
    legend(rows(3))
```

The option `t>1600` asks that the in-sample predictions be plotted starting at "time period" 1600 (this dataset has a time index that runs from 1 to 2015). The `xline` option asks for a vertical line at t=2015 (in the previous example, this was to indicate that at t=2015, forecasts were out-of-sample), and the `legend(row(3))` specifies that you want the graph legend to placed in three separate rows -- this is just graph formatting.

---

### Update 2

The OP has asked about adding explanatory variables in the equations for the conditional mean and the conditional variance. This is explained in the help file for `mgarch dcc`. The syntax is

```
        mgarch dcc eq [eq ... eq] [if] [in] [, options]
    where each eq has the form
        (depvarlist = [indepvars] [, eqoptions])
```

- The optional argument `[indepvars]` allows you to add explanatory variables to the conditional mean to any one, to sets of, or to all the dependent variables at the same time.
- The optional equation options, `eqoptions`, has the following optional component

  ```
    het(varlist)             include varlist in the specification of the conditional variance
  ```

which allows you to add explanatory variables to the conditional variance equation of any one, to sets of, or to all the dependent variables at the same time.

#### Example

So, for example, if  you had three series `return1`, `return2` and `return3`, and three independent variables `x1`, `x2` and `x3`, then the command

```
mgarch dcc (return1 return2 = x1 x2, het(x1 x2 x3)) (return3 = x3, het(x1 x2 x3))
```

implies that the variables `x1` and `x2` enter the conditional mean of `return1` and `return2`, `x3` enters the conditional mean of `return3`. Similarly, `x1`, `x2` and `x3` enter the conditional variance of `return1`, `return2` and `return3`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helps me a lot. I had some other questions because i dont know how to interpret the results. The example is about forecasting the correlations, but I dont want to do that. I only want to test the correlation in the past. So i suggest that i dont need the "tsappend, add(50)" command. The only thing that i want to do is to calculate the dynamic correlation for every time unit. Is the predict command still the correct command to do this? and what do i have to use for my dataset for this command: t>1600, ///
    legend(rows(3)) xline(2015). What do the numbers say?

Comment: I have updated the answer to address your follow-up questions.

Comment: It works, thank you! I also read that it is possible to add explanatory variables in the DCC. Is it also possible to add Control variables to my model and do you know how to do that?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think you should read the pdf help manual carefully for very good examples of the use of all the features of `mgarch`.

Comment: @M.Assad you should consider accepting the answer as correct if you have no further queries.

Comment: where can i find the help manual, because i have a lot more to know??

Comment: @M.Assad Are you using Stata 11 or 12? Then you have electronic access to the entire pdf manuals which used to be shipped as paper copies with Stata prior to version 11. 

I am assuming that you know that you can get "online help" by typing `help mgarch dcc` inside Stata. In Stata 11, the pdf documentation is a link right at the bottom of the help file. In Stata 12, there is a link to the pdf documentation in the top right hand `Also see` tab.

Comment: @M.Assad please see this section: http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask of the FAQ about accepting answered questions.

Comment: i am using stata 12 and found the help function. but what i cant find is a manual which explains how to interpret the stata output of the Mgarch DCC model. Do you have a link or a document where it is explained?

Comment: Like I mentioned previously, in the pdf manual, there are fully worked examples starting on page 251. Follow the steps I outlined in my previous comment to bring up the pdf help manual from the online help manual.

Comment: I didn't had Adobe reader on my Mac, thats why it didn't work. Thanks for the support

Comment: No problem. Best of luck with your study.

Comment: Thank you!! Is it possible to have a conditional quasi correlation of 1,6 between 2 indices? I know that the Pearson correlation is always between -1 and +1, but i am not familiar with the conditional quasi correlations. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @M.Assad I suggest you ask a new question with what exact commands you ran, what output you got, and what questions you have regarding it. That way, you can get help from the entire community. :)

Comment: I did, but no reply yet. Anyway, i have another question regarding the prediction of the correlation. after doing the dcc garch model, i did the predict H*, variance command. Is it correct that these are the dynamic correlations? why does stata say that these are the variances?