# Estimating correlation with DCC GARCH

Tags: correlation, variance, garch

I have used a DCC Garch model to estimate the co-movement between 2 indices using the following command in Stata:

```
mgarch dcc (X Y = , noconstant), arch(1) garch(1) constraints(1 2)
predict H*, variance
```

After the variance prediction I get a column with the variances per time unit. My question is how to transform the variances to the correlations per time unit?

Comment: Could [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41282/dynamic-conditional-correlation-in-stata) be helpful for you?

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the fact that the correlation at any time $t$ of two series in the DCC GARCH 
model, $Y_{1t}, Y_{2t}$ is just $\tfrac{\mathbb{C}(Y_{1t}, Y_{2t})}{\sqrt{\mathbb{V}(Y_{1t})\mathbb{V}(Y_{1t})}}$.

You can compute this manually as in the following example

```
webuse stocks, clear

// fit the DCC GARCH model
mgarch dcc (toyota nissan = , noconstant) (honda = , noconstant), ///
    arch(1) garch(1)

// predict the conditional covariances
predict condvar*, variance 

// generate the correlations
g condcorr_nissan_toyota = condvar_nissan_toyota/ ///
    (sqrt(condvar_nissan_nissan)*sqrt(condvar_toyota_toyota))
g condcorr_honda_toyota = condvar_honda_toyota/ ///
    (sqrt(condvar_honda_honda)*sqrt(condvar_toyota_toyota))
g condcorr_honda_nissan = condvar_honda_nissan/ ///
    (sqrt(condvar_nissan_nissan)*sqrt(condvar_honda_honda))

// plot the conditional correlations
tsline condcorr_nissan_toyota condcorr_honda_toyota condcorr_honda_nissan, ///
    legend(rows(3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are some very important steps to be taken before defining your time series.

You can generate time variable first:

```
//generate time variable t
gen t=_n
//time series set
tsset t
```

Then start the above steps.

After all the analysis is done, you can copy paste the real date to the  value. Then it will give you a good graph. Otherwise, especially for 5-day per week data, it may create problems.

Comment: Does that generate the correlations the OP asked for?

Answer (score 0):

This is my do file for command to study the dcc between stock return of one country Chile and U.S with t-distribution. I hope it is helpful.

```
gen t=_n
tsset t, daily
mgarch dcc (reche=L.reche L.reus) (reus=L.reus), arch (1) garch(1) distribution(t)
predict H*, variance
gen corr_che_us= H_reus_reche/(sqrt( H_reche_reche)*sqrt( H_reus_reus))
tsline corr_che_us
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can you help me to identify the mistake.I am trying to generate conditional variance plots.These are my commands: 
mgarch dcc ( zar euro), arch(1) garch(2)
predict H*, variance
gen corr zar euro= H_euro_zar/(sqrt( H_zar_zar)*sqrt( H_euro_euro))
and 
I am getting this answer:

variable zar already defined

Answer (score -1):

The predict command should generate variances and covariances? In which case just generate the correlations manually via the correlation formula.

Comment: Should you clarify you answer and provide some details.